# Magento2 - Need to add External Images from external media host. How the image path is stored in DB?

Tags: magento2, product-images, media-images, external-images

The `Magento OOTB` functionality has the option of adding `images` from the external media host.

I just need to use both `locally stored images` and `images from different media hosts` instead of `one media host`.

Answer (score 0):

The storing of images in the DB for a product from the admin side is handled explicitly by a Handler.

Try adding your logic in the execute function in the **Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\CreateHandler** file.

Try adding a preference or plugin for this one in **etc/adminhtml**.

Comment: Did you achieve this? If yes, please share the documentation if any